# Can't I change img src to hover image with onmouseover property when I turn data from vue to for statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, hover

```
<li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" class="nav-list" @mouseenter="onMouseEnter" @mouseleave="onMouseLeave">
  <router-link class="nav-link" :to="nameLowerCase(user.enName)">
    <img :src="imgSrc(user)">
    <p>{{user.enName}}</p>
  </router-link>
</li>
```

data: function () {
    return {
      isHovering : false,
    }
  },

```
imgSrc(user) {
  const trimmedUrl = user.darkIconImageUrl;
  const trimmedColorUrl = user.lightIconImageUrl;    
  const trimmedBase = trim(AWS.BASEURL_ORIGINAL, '/');
  const trimmedBucket = trim(AWS.BUCKET, '/');
  if(this.isHovering) {
    return `${trimmedBase}/${trimmedBucket}/${trimmedColorUrl}`;
  } 
  return `${trimmedBase}/${trimmedBucket}/${trimmedUrl}`;
},
```

Because they share data, hovering over a menu turns them into hover images. I tried onmouseover and it didn't work. Help. Please understand that I'm not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do something like this?

```
<li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" class="nav-list" @mouseenter="onMouseEnter(user, $event)" @mouseleave="onMouseLeave(user, $event)">
  <router-link class="nav-link" :to="nameLowerCase(user.enName)">
    <img :src="imgSrc[user.id]">
    <p>{{user.enName}}</p>
  </router-link>
</li>


data: function(){
    return {
        imgSrc: [],
    }
},

methods: {
    onMouseEnter(user, event){
        this.setImgSrc(user, true);
    },
    onMouseLeave(user, event){
        this.setImgSrc(user, false);
    },
    setImgSrc(user, isHover) {
      const trimmedUrl = user.darkIconImageUrl;
      const trimmedColorUrl = user.lightIconImageUrl;    
      const trimmedBase = trim(AWS.BASEURL_ORIGINAL, '/');
      const trimmedBucket = trim(AWS.BUCKET, '/');
      if(isHover) {
        this.imgSrc[user.id] = `${trimmedBase}/${trimmedBucket}/${trimmedColorUrl}`;
      } 
      this.imgSrc[user.id] = `${trimmedBase}/${trimmedBucket}/${trimmedUrl}`;
    }, 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it did not solve. Click to change the image, and still change the other image.

Comment: @hoony, You was talking about hovering image not a clicking.

Comment: @hoony, also you can't use `if(this.isHovering) {` because you have `v-for` loop.

Comment: @hoony, I have updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Comment: I'm talking about hover.
I've applied the code I've responded to, and when I hover over it, the image doesn't change, only the click changes the image.

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't checked it yet. I'll test it right away.

Comment: I tested it. still not working.
Is there anything I missed?

Comment: It seems to be caused by shared user data because it is a loop, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: @hoony, I have already provided to you the solution to use `imgSrc[user.id]` as array in my previous update. Do you still have unworking li-list?

Comment: Yes I used imgSrc[user.id] as array in your previous update. but still unworking.

Comment: @hoony, do you have some error in the browser console?

Comment: @hoony, I have made another update to my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Inspired by your code, I could solve it.
I applied [ for .. in ] to the component and sent the data of [ for .. in ] to props.
The isHover is not shared because the component is separated according to the size of [ for .. in ]
So I finally solved it

Comment: @hoony, ok. That's great!